# UIPickerview remains blank despite call to reloadAllComponents.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My Picker is added to the view before the data that populates it is downloaded from the internet.

When the data is received I call

```
-(void)refreshPicker 
{
 [pickerViewController reloadAllComponents];
}
```

But the pickerView remains blank, not showing the titles of the rows, but if I move it, the rows then update and you can see them. So basically it appears empty until you move it. Is there a trick to get it to draw the rows? Like make it scroll programmatically?

Many Thanks,
Code

Comment: I would check another time that the datasource delegate is set correctly (never mind, if you use IB or the code). If everything is fine there, how do you store(load) you data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pickerView reloadAllComponents]